# Unable to use AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> ad = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap); as below

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

```java
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class base {
    
    
    static AppiumDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        
        try {
            openCalculator();
        
        }catch(Exception exp) {
            System.out.println(exp.getCause());
            System.out.print(exp.getMessage());
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

    } //main
    
    public static void openCalculator () throws MalformedURLException {
        
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities ();
        
        cap.setCapability("deviceName", "");
        cap.setCapability("udid", "");
        cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "");
        cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.transsion.calculator");
        cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.transsion.calculator.Calculator");
        
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        
        driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url, cap);
        
        //AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> ad = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);
        
        System.out.println("Application Started..........");
    } //openCalculator
```

Comment: Please edit your question to say what your problem is. If your code is giving an error, please include the error message. We don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: @Kate Paulk:  this the error. Is not accepting this driver = new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url, cap)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the APK Path.

```
cap.setCapability("appium:app", "C:\\Appium\\app-debug.apk");
```

Comment: Did you mean as should include the above in my capability and pls how exactly should i place it.

Comment: And Which directory am i getting this "C:\\Appium\\app-debug.apk" from. pls eleborate. Thanks

Comment: APK is your app under test.  You should have a debug build that can be automated.  It should live somewhere in your java project, for example your src directory.

Comment: Thanks@ToastMan.Will try it.